# "Butterflies have interested me" or "Butterflies had interested me" - which is correct?

Tags: word-choice, tense, verbs

Is this correct?  Butterflies _____ interested me for a long time.  Which do you use, have or had?

Comment: They can both be used.  The choice depends on what you're trying to say.

Comment: I'd use "haven't".

Comment: You can even leave the blank unpopulated: "Butterflies interested me for a long time."

Answer (score 2):

If you use "have", it means your interest in butterflies began in the past and continues to the present time.

You would use "had" to indicate that your interest began before another event in the past (and may or may not continue to the present time). For example:

> Butterflies had interested me for a long time when I was chosen to
>   lead the expedition to follow the monarch migration in 2013.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if butterflies used to interest you (past tense), in this case you would say:

> Butterflies **had** interested me for a long time.

If you are still interested in butterflies (present tense), you would say:

> Butterflies **have** interested me for a long time.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of additional context, the answer is simple:

***have***

> Butterflies **have** interested me for a long time.